# How to make Windows Timer running in background thread

Tags: c++, windows

Question : How do you make a timer tick in the background? That is the thread that create the timer thread can still do something else while clock is ticking.

Attempt:
-Using _beginthreadex() --> It seems to have race condition

```
class Timer{
 ...
 static unsigned __stdcall tick(void *param){
    while(1){
        Timer::timer++;
        Sleep(Timer::timer*1000);
    }
    return 1;
}
}

.....
HANDLE time_thread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(0, 0, &Timer::tick,0,0,NULL);
...
//test for 20 seconds
//want to do something while the clock is not 20 seconds
//the mainthread here still has to receive input
//What is the proper way to do it?

while (Timer::getTime() != 20){
   cout << Timer::getTime()
}

CloseHandle(time_thread);
...
```

NOTE: Iam using Visual Studio 2008, not 11 so I do not have C++11 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with what you have here.  You've created a thread that updates a member variable `timer` forever and your main use of it is a tight/fast loop that prints (presumably) that time until it reaches 20.  What is it not doing?  Technically there's a race condition of incrementing that value versus checking it in another thread, but for the purposes of this example it should be fine...

**EDIT:**  try this for non-blocking input with full input control:

```
HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
while ( true ) {
    if ( WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject( hStdIn, 1000 ) ) {
        // read input
        INPUT_RECORD inputRecord;
        DWORD events;
        if ( ReadConsoleInput( hStdIn, &inputRecord, 1, &events ) ) {
            if ( inputRecord.EventType == KEY_EVENT ) {
                printf( "got char %c %s\n",
                    inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar,
                    inputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown ? "down" : "up" );
            }
        }
    }
    printf( "update clock\n" );
}
```

Comment: it will print out like : 00000001111111111112222222222222222333333333333333333.....and so on. How do you make it so that while it is incrementing, the main thread can still recieve input? Say like. If it is not 20, you still can punch in word

Comment: are we talking about a console program or a Windows GUI program?

Comment: if you're just looking to check for console input for 20 seconds, then continue if you don't have any, you should look in `GetStdHandle (STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` and `WaitForSingleObject` and just skip the thread.  You might also need to `SetConsoleMode` based on what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is not GUI program, a console rather. I just want to make a simple clock that ticks, and at some points in time I can do something else(call somefunction like end), but while it tick, i can input on the console

Comment: you can use `WaitForSingleObject` on the standard input handle for 1000 ms (1 second) in a loop.  update the clock every time it comes out of the wait, and check for input.

Comment: Isn't it making the std_input unresponsive(wait)? I began to think I need to spawn a whole new process? Is it right the way I think

Comment: You don't need a new process, no.  It doesn't make it unresponsive because as soon as there's input, it stops waiting and allows you to read it.  It stops waiting when there's 1) input waiting, or 2) the timeout expires.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you've misunderstood how the system timers work and how to use them - the whole point is that they *automatically* run in the background, so you don't have to do your own thread management.

This has examples and explanations of Windows timers in general, and you can use it if you're trying to roll your own `Timer` class: [Timers Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial)

This is the `Timer` class that comes with Windows.NET, with a code example at the bottom: [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

**Edited to add:**

Here's a version of the Win32 timer example (from the turorial page) adapted for a non-MFC app:

```
int nTimerID;

void Begin(HWND hWindow_who_gets_the_tick)
{
    // create the timer to alert your window:
    nTimerID = SetTimer(hWindow_who_gets_the_tick, uElapse, NULL);
}

void Stop()
{
    // destroy the timer
    KillTimer(nTimerID);
}
```

See [MSDN: Timer functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Then inside your window procedure, you get the `WM_TIMER` message and respond as you like.

Alternatively, the timer can call a user-defined procedure. See [SetTimer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: I 'll take a look. Thank you. Is there any solution without MFC